# Pythonnet passing arguments to c# dll

Tags: c#, string, dll, path, python.net

I'm using Pythonnet 2.4.0 to access a C# dll. I have a Windows 10 machine with Python 3.7.6.

I'm trying to use a method that only takes a path string as argument, but I don't manage to make it work.

```
import clr
sys.path.append(os.getcwd)
clr.AddReference('C#Wrapper')

path = "C:\\Users\\Username\\Folder"

c#class.method(string path)
```

If I use the overloads attribute from pythonnet, it tells me that the argument should be of type System.String, however doing something like below didn't help either:

```
path = System.String("C:\\Users\\Username\\Folder")
```

I keep getting a TypeError: No Method matches given arguments.
Do I need to encode the string or make a char array in order for c# to be able to understand it?

## Edit:

I've just found a test function in the dll that only takes an Int32 argument and I have the same problem! I tried things like:

```
import ctypes
c#class.testmethod(ctypes.c_int32(1))

from System import Int32
c#class.testmethod(Int32(1))
```

but nothing worked. How can I pass arguments to the c# dll?

## [Solved]:

I figured it out myself. In the second case I simply forgot to instantiate a class object. I should have done:

```
classobj = c#class()
classobj.testmethod(1)
```

This made me realize that in the first case I had basically the same issue. I followed a Visual Basic manual to write my Python program where it said something like this:

```
classobj = c#class
```

However in Python you need to write:

```
classobj = c#class()
```

So the missing parenthesis was causing the *TypeError: No Method matches given arguments*, which was very misleading. The type conversion and passing of arguments is perfectly handled thanks to the amazing developers of phythonnet! I won't delete this question in case other people experience the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The answer above is correct: [Pythonnet passing arguments to c# dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60936687/pythonnet-passing-arguments-to-c-sharp-dll).
I'd just like clarify what it means.

The error occurred because a method from a class was *accessed without instantiating the object*.

The solution is one of the two:

- create an instance of the class
- mark the .net method as static

The problem was that the error message is misleading, it says "No method matches given arguments". Which made me try to find the right argument.

By me this occurred when I forgot to add the static modifier to the .net method I called.